# Extracting excel files from the FTP to BigQuery using Cloud Functions

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, ftp, google-cloud-functions

I am working on creating an automated script to download files from a FTP and store them into BigQuery.

Problem is that BigQuery accepts only `.csv` files. For this reason I am looking for ways to handle also `.xlsx` and `.xls` files, conditional on that I am planning to put this batch code in the Cloud.

I am mentioning the latter as one way of going about to convert `.xlsx` files to `.csv` is to use something like:

```
import pandas as pd
data_xls = pd.read_excel('file_on_ftp.xlsx')
data_xls.to_csv('csvfile.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

However, this will create local files somewhere in the temporary storage. Obviously with Cloud Functions I have to then monitor whether the file has been deleted afterwards or not, making it not reliable when one cloud function would Crash.

Are there therefore better ways to handle `.xlsx` loading into BigQuery? Or is this the way to go?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46796885/bigquery-loading-excel-file

Comment: Answer suggests to use Google Drive. This is not a production ready solution and the question is not well defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be interested this guide, which was just recently published: ["Streaming data from Cloud Storage into BigQuery using Cloud Functions"](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/streaming-data-from-cloud-storage-into-bigquery-using-cloud-functions).

The general architecture would be:

1. upload the files in question from FTP to Cloud Storage
2. your Cloud Function receives the upload event from Cloud Storage
3. your Cloud Function loads the file into memory (no storage on disk)
4. your Cloud Function streams the data to BigQuery

I'm not sure if #1 suits your need to ensure that the file is not left behind somewhere, but I think it's probably the best possible solution if you are operating under the assumption that the file needs to be uploaded to GCP somewhere (the alternative would be streaming to BigQuery directly from your local machine, or an instance that is under your control).

Comment: Yes but where is the FTP extraction part?

Comment: FTP requires putting the files onto the local disk. If you want to avoid doing this on GCP, you'll need to do something custom to go from FTP->GCS. See ["FTP to Google Storage"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43486480/ftp-to-google-storage), ["FTP to GCS Transfer"](https://serverfault.com/questions/813106/ftp-to-gcs-transfer) or ["Cloud Storage FUSE"](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse)

Comment: You can put the FTP files on Google Cloud Function's local temporary directory called `/tmp`. That's the only writable part on filesystem. Read more here: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#file_system

Answer (score 1):

I good method is to extract the file from FTP to GCS through Cloud Functions. Like @[Dustin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54751322/2649145) mentioned, you can then stream the data into BigQuery from  GCS

Here's a way to extract files from FTP via Cloud Functions

```
#import libraries
from google.cloud import storage
import wget


def importFile(request):

 #set storage client
 client = storage.Client()

 # get bucket
 bucket = client.get_bucket('BUCKET-NAME') #without gs://
 blob = bucket.blob('file-name.csv')

 #See if file already exists
 if blob.exists() == False:

    #copy file to google storage
    try:
        link = 'ftp://account:password@ftp.domain.com/folder/file.csv' #for non-public ftp files
        ftpfile = wget.download(link, out='/tmp/destination-file-name.csv') #save downloaded file in /tmp folder of Cloud Functions
        blob.upload_from_filename(ftpfile)
        print('Copied file to Google Storage!')

    #print error if file doesn't exists
    except BaseException as error:
        print('An exception occurred: {}'.format(error))

 #print error if file already exists in Google Storage
 else:
    print('File already exists in Google Storage')
```