# Downloading files from Firebase (like FTP)

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I've essentially been using firebase for storage and my last computer got wiped, and I'm trying to download all the sites files that I've been hosting on firebase. I can't figure out how to do this and the answers I've found seem overcomplicated.

Comment: There is no built-in FTP console for Cloud Storage for Firebase. But you can use the API to get your files from it. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43486480/ftp-to-google-storage

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in FTP console for Google Cloud Storage. But you can use the [Firebase API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage) to get your files from it.

Also see [FTP to Google Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43486480/ftp-to-google-storage) for an example FTP server that a developer made on top of Google Cloud Storage.